# Call function by reference

Tags: angular, typescript

Suppose I obtain a function by a condition as follows:

```
const func = myBooleanCondition ? this.userService.addUserGroup : this.userService.removeUserGroup;
```

And both of these have the same signature:

```
addUserGroup(username: string, group: string): Observable<string[]>
```

So I'd like to apply the parameters to this function:

```
const result = func.apply(this.username, 'value');
```

But this isn't the right way to do so. How do I achieve this in typescript (javascript)?

Comment: it's just `func(this.username, 'value');`. `func` is a pointer to the function object so you just invoke it.

Comment: Why not just `func(this.username, 'value')`? `Function.prototype.apply` allows to pass a specific `this` but this is not what you need AFAIK

Comment: It all hinges on whatever *But this isn't the right way to do so* means? Why is this not "right"?

Comment: right: working and preferably clean. clean is also debatable but let’s focus on working.

Comment: Tried the simple application but needed the 'this' reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do `this.userService.addUserGroup(/*...*/)`, `this` within the call is the user service. When you call a function using its `call` or `apply` method, the first argument you give it is the `this` value to use, then for `call` you list the arguments to pass it or for `apply` you give it an array of the arguments to pass it.

So if you want to call it with `this` set to the user service and two discrete arguments, you'd use `call` like this:

```
const result = func.call(this.userService, this.username, 'value');
```

The equivalent `apply` would be this, but I don't think you want that in your example:

```
const result = func.call(this.userService, [this.username, 'value']);
```

If the user service doesn't care about the `this` value during the call (some services do, some don't), you don't need `call`/`apply` at all:

```
const result = func(this.username, 'value');
```

Comment: I needed to pass this.userService, so the first suggestion won, thanks for the explanation. These scopes are a bit confusing at first.

Comment: @BalázsNémeth - Glad that helped! (Just FWIW, `this` and scope are quite different things. I only mention that because having the terminology a bit wrong can make it hard to search for information.) Happy coding!